# Why does my video not play when I re-enter my app after exiting?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to build a video playing Android app using Kotlin. I followed this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/14273655-mediaplayer-simplified-video-playback-on-android

My video can play, but when I exit the app and re-enter it, or turn my screen off and on again, the video image turns to black, though the audio still plays.

I tried using onRestart(), onStart(), and onPause()

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    print("hello")
    onPrepared(mediaPlayer)
    mediaPlayer.start()
  }

  override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    print("hello")
    onPrepared(mediaPlayer)
    mediaPlayer.start()
  }

  override fun onRestart() {
    super.onRestart()
    print("hello")
    onPrepared(mediaPlayer)
    mediaPlayer.start()
  }
```

but it doesn't work.

What I want is basically to just have the video resume playing once I re-enter the app (like youtube). I've tried using Exoplayer too but can't figure out how to play a local file.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to reset() the video to properly stop it. Try:

```
private var mMediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1)
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mediaPlayer?.prepare()
    mediaPlayer?.start()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super?.onPause()
    mediaPlayer?.reset()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    mediaPlayer?.release()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried it, but now I think my app just keeps stopping? It gives me this warning/alert "(app name) keeps stopping".

Comment: What does the log say? Try removing your onStart and onResume. You shouldn't need them in this case.

Comment: i removed onStart and onResume, it still keeps stopping. the log says 2021-10-09 05:35:51.746 3202-3202/com.raywenderlich.mediaplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.raywenderlich.mediaplayer, PID: 3202
    java.lang.IllegalStateException

Comment: I updated my answer with more detail. See also https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer

Comment: thank you very much for your help! the original tutorial didn't use MediaPlayer like how the documentation did, and when I tried it, it didn't work... But I found another tutorial using VideoView that works! Unfortunately, it doesn't resume the video at where it stopped when I exit and re-enter the app. Would it be possible for you to help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: link to my new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69504312/how-to-resume-video-where-it-stopped-using-videoview